# UnicodeDecodeError：'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0 illegal multibyte sequence

Tags: python, encoding, pickle

I use python 3.4 with win 7 64-bit system. I ran the following code:

```
      6   """ load single batch of cifar """
      7   with open(filename, 'r') as f:
----> 8     datadict = pickle.load(f)
      9     X = datadict['data']
```

The wrong message is `UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: illegal multibyte sequence`

I changed the line 7 as:

```
      6   """ load single batch of cifar """
      7   with open(filename, 'r'，encoding='utf-8') as f:
----> 8     datadict = pickle.load(f)
      9     X = datadict['data']
```

The wrong message became `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte`.

The message finally points to the Python34\lib\codecs.py in decode(self, input, final).

```
    311         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    312         data = self.buffer + input
--> 313         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    314         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    315         self.buffer = data[consumed:]
```

I further changed the code as:

```
      6 """ load single batch of cifar """ 
      7 with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
----> 8 datadict = pickle.load(f) 
      9 X = datadict['data'] 10 Y = datadict['labels']
```

Well, this time is `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)`.

What is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: What is the full traceback of the last version? The `pickle` documentation states that the file object *should return bytes*, so you **have** to open the file object in binary mode with `'rb'`, but you now have a new error. How was the pickle file created in the first place?

Comment: ‘ import pickle as pickle
import numpy as np
import os

def load_CIFAR_batch(filename):
  """ load single batch of cifar """
  with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    datadict = pickle.load(f)’  This is how the pickle is created.

Comment: You can [edit] your post to add more information.

Comment: You are telling me how the pickle is being **loaded**, not how it was written.

Comment: pickle is the standard python module. I did not touch it.

Comment: No, I am asking how the file was created. Someone used `pickle.dump()` or `pickle.dumps()` to produce pickle data. I'd like to see how the file output you are trying to load was produced.

Comment: the file was downloaded from http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html. It seems that the files are produced by cPickle by the Python 2.X. However, I use Python 3.4, in which cPickle and pickle are merged. Does it mean it is not back compatible?

Comment: I'll have a look; worst case it data would need to be converted first, but I think we can get away with using a protocol specifier. Not sure when I can download the datafile (travelling by train makes downloading a little harder).

Answer (score 16):

Pickle files are binary data files, so you always have to open the file with the `'rb'` mode when loading. Don't try to use a text mode here.

You are trying to load a Python 2 pickle that contains string data. You'll have to tell `pickle.load()` how to convert that data to Python 3 strings, or to leave them as bytes.

The default is to try and decode those strings as ASCII, and that decoding fails. See the [`pickle.load()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.load):

> Optional keyword arguments are *fix_imports*, *encoding* and *errors*, which are used to control compatibility support for pickle stream generated by Python 2. If *fix_imports* is true, pickle will try to map the old Python 2 names to the new names used in Python 3. The *encoding* and *errors* tell pickle how to decode 8-bit string instances pickled by Python 2; these default to ‘ASCII’ and ‘strict’, respectively. The *encoding* can be ‘bytes’ to read these 8-bit string instances as bytes objects.

Setting the encoding to `latin1` allows you to import the data directly:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    datadict = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
```

It appears that it is the `numpy` array data that is causing the problems  here as all strings in the set use ASCII characters *only*.

The alternative would by to use `encoding='bytes'` but then all the filenames and top-level dictionary keys are `bytes` objects and you'd have to decode those or prefix all your key literals with `b`.

Answer (score 9):

if you will open file with utf-8,then you need write:

```
open(file_name, 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
```

if you will open file with GBK,then you need do:

```
open(file_name, 'rb')
```

hope to solve your problem!

Answer (score 2):

If you using python3.7+, you can set a env var to solve this.

```py
export PYTHONUTF8=1  # linux / macOS
set PYTHONUTF8=1  # windows
```

More info:
https://dev.to/methane/python-use-utf-8-mode-on-windows-212i
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50933341/1745885