# How to check what default encoding is used by Python's open() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

I am planning to set the environment variable PYTHONUTF8 = 1 on my machine, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50933194/how-do-i-set-the-pythonutf8-environment-variable-to-enable-utf-8-encoding-by-def), to ensure that the open() function uses UTF8 as the default encoding. But I also want to make sure that my code doesn't silently break on another machine. So I would like my script to contain a check: it should check what encoding is used by open() and issue a warning message if it's not UTF8. How can my script check that?

Comment: Why not be explicit and ensure that all `open` calls done in your program include the argument `encoding="utf8"`?

Comment: Call `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding or `locale.getpreferredencoding()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding and check they return `'UTF-8'`?

Comment: You should put encoding explicit ("explicit is better then implicit" is one mantra of Python). But in short: all modern platform but Windows uses UTF-8 as default. Windows still use local encoding (it depend on language).

Answer (score 0):

From the Python [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) documentation:

> In text mode, if *encoding* is not specified the encoding used is platform dependent: `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is called to get the current locale encoding.

But if you don't want your code to "silently break on another machine", simply specify the encoding that you want and don't rely on environment variables and defaults.