# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 1679: character maps to <undefined> in GitHub Action

Tags: python, github-actions, cicd

I have a GitHub action that runs to build and release a Python package that I am building. At the point of installing dependencies (on Windows compute), I am faced with the above error. This is the full stack trace,

```
  [21 lines of output]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.13\x64\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.13\x64\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.13\x64\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 132, in get_requires_for_build_editable
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-h6r6afd3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 450, in get_requires_for_build_editable
      return self.get_requires_for_build_wheel(config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-h6r6afd3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-h6r6afd3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-h6r6afd3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-h6r6afd3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
    File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.13\x64\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
      return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 1679: character maps to <undefined>
  [end of output]
```

What could be the problem here?

This is the exact run that I am having the issue with,

https://github.com/MinuraPunchihewa/ai-text-to-sql/actions/runs/5523938376/jobs/10075748805

Comment: The process is trying to write Unicode characters to a stdout with the wrong encoding (cp1252 instead of UTF-8). The fix is to set a command line arg or environment variable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50933194/how-do-i-set-the-pythonutf8-environment-variable-to-enable-utf-8-encoding-by-def

Comment: How can I resolve this in my context? I added the following as a command to my .yaml file, but it still did not work: `python -X utf8`.

Comment: Try setting that for the python process that runs pip: so `python -X utf8 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: It does not seem to work.