# PyInstaller: UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 180: illegal multibyte sequence

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I met a Traceback while try to convert a python file to exe under Windows 10: UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 180: illegal multibyte sequence
Please help, thanks.

**Here is test.spec file:**

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
import sys   
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000000)
block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['test.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='test',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

**Here is Traceback log:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 838, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 784, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 33, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 410, in __init__
    self.console, self.uac_admin, self.uac_uiaccess)
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py", line 1076, in create_manifest
    old_xml = f.read()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 180: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Here is a link for reference:

[UnicodeDecodeError：'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0 illegal multibyte sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165639/unicodedecodeerror-gbk-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x80-in-position-0-illegal-mult)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works simply by changing Python file name from Chinese to English.